# Artifacts when generating images with Blender

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I have noticed that some images that I'm rendering with Cycles gets a weird artefact (horizontal lines) see pictures. What is it causing this? I don't get it when rendering with Eevee

[image]